# Draggable Clones Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Any ideas on how to make the clones draggable?

```
            $("#draggable").draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                cursor: 'pointer',
            });

            $("#snaptarget").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                       var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
                       var newId = '#draggable_'+randomnumber;

                        $(ui.helper).clone(true).removeAttr('id').attr('id',newId).appendTo('#snaptarget');                     
                        $(newId).draggable();                   
                }
            });
```

$(newId).draggable(); does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't start IDs with a `#`. As you are here:

```
var newId = '#draggable_'+randomnumber;
```

It should be:

```
var newId = 'draggable_'+randomnumber;
```

Then this:

```
$(newId).draggable();
```

should be:

```
$('#' + newId).draggable();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/M3UWp/

So you end up with:

```
var newId = 'draggable_'+randomnumber;
$(ui.helper).clone(true).removeAttr('id').attr('id',newId).appendTo('#snaptarget');  
$('#' + newId).draggable();
```

Comment: One more question, how do i stop the cloning of the cloned item, just need it to be draggable.

Comment: I am trying to do something like http://examples.placona.co.uk/drag_drop except with the latest version of jquery.

Comment: @jbatson - I don't know much about draggable, but I took a quick look at the docs, and moved your code into the `stop:` callback of `draggable`. Seems to work. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/M3UWp/1/